# Flyway job is not executing command

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, migration, flyway

## The problem

I have a flyway job that is meant to be performing migrations on a postgres database.
The job doesn't seem to be running the command and inspection of the jobs logs only output flyway documentation.

### Expectations

I expect the log inspection to be a synopsis of the migrations occurred.
I also have installed pgweb to allow for observability and after connecting to my postgres pod, it is clear no tables have been created at all.

Here is a photo of the expected output from kubectl logs flyway-pod
[image: Migrations expected output]

### What I get

This is the output of kubectl logs flyway-pod
[image: Flyway Logs output]
As you can see it prints the usage guide rather than a sign that the migration occurred.

### What I have tried -explanation

I have so far been moving the connection command around.

I have commented out the locations where I have tried placing the command.
I have tried it in 3 locations.

1. Inside the original Flyway Dockerfile and nowhere else.
2. Inside the docker compose file near the flyway service and nowhere else.
3. Inside the Kubernetes Flyway job and nowhere else.

## Code

Here are my files and setup.

### Kubernetes files

What follows are the relevant Kubernetes files used to setup my cluster.

#### Flyway Job:

Here is the Flyway job:

```
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: flyway-migration-job
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: flyway
        image: flyway/flyway:6.3.1
        command: ["flyway", "-url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-master:5432/wallet", "-user=test_user", "-password=testuser1234", "-schemas=wallet", "-connectRetries=60 migrate"]
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

#### Postgres Deployment and Service

##### Postgres Deployment file

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres-master
  labels:
    app: postgres-master
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres-master
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres-master
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres-master
          image: postgres:13
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: wallet
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: test_user
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: testuser1234
```

##### Postgres service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-master
  labels: 
    app: postgres-master
spec: 
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
  selector: 
    app: postgres-master
```

### Docker files

As I am building my images locally and pulling them into my cluster using kind, I will attach my relevant Dockerfiles.

#### Flyway Dockerfile

```
FROM flyway/flyway:7.7.3-alpine

COPY ./migrations/sql /flyway/sql/

#CMD ["flyway -url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-master:5432/wallet -user=test_user -password=testuser1234  -connectRetries=60 -schemas=wallet migrate"]
```

#### Flyway SQL script

This script is stored inside migrations/sql

```
CREATE TABLE wallet.transaction_events (
    transaction_version int,
    transaction_type VARCHAR(200),
    coins int,
    transaction_id VARCHAR(500),
    wallet_id VARCHAR(500)
)
```

#### Docker compose

Here is the docker compose file that I use to build my images before pulling into kind/my cluster.

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  web:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: wallet-api-web
    depends_on: 
      - flyway
    ports: 
      - "8080:8080"
  postgres-db:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./utils/db.Dockerfile
    container_name: postgres-db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: testuser1234
      POSTGRES_USER: test_user
      POSTGRES_DB: wallet
    image: postgres:13
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always

  flyway:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./migrations/Dockerfile
    #command: -url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-master:5432/wallet -user=test_user -password=testuser1234 -schemas=wallet -connectRetries=60 migrate 
    container_name: flyway-migrations
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: flyway/flyway:6.3.1
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/migrations/sql:/flyway/sql
```

I think I have covered everything required to provide context to my problem but if any clarifications are required feel free to ask.

I really appreciate any help with getting these migrations working.
Thank you

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You command is in array syntax, that means that each parameter must be a separate element.
You have two parameters in the last element, which flyway does not understand.

To fix:

```
"-connectRetries=60 migrate"]
```

change to

```
"-connectRetries=60", "migrate"]
```